# How can I make my iPad a TCP Socket Server?

Tags: ipad, sockets

Can anyone point me to an example or an explanation of how to get a server going on an iPad? I want to use TCP sockets and I've already downloaded the current AsyncSocket stuff but it's trickier looking than I thought. I've been researching but everyone talks about iOS as the client and some PC as the server. I would like to set up my iPad as a local server for a game I'm writing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C socket api. Every valid C standard library is also valid in Objective-C. [Here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) is a nice guide for programming sockets with C.